# Sorting python list containing positive and negative elements

Tags: python-2.7, list, sorting

I want to sort the following list containing positive and negative elements in descending order. It does sort partially i.e. finds/sorts the positive elements correctly. But, the negative elements seems wrong.

```
>>> sorted([u'-10.44%', u'-9.35%', u'-4.20%', u'-1.23%', u'-15.37%', u'-13.51%', u'-11.94%', u'10.07%', u'0.32%', u'-4.02%', u'-12.69%', u'-17.28%'],reverse=True)
[u'10.07%', u'0.32%', u'-9.35%', u'-4.20%', u'-4.02%', u'-17.28%', u'-15.37%', u'-13.51%', u'-12.69%', u'-11.94%', u'-10.44%', u'-1.23%']
```

I was hoping that it will print in this (descending) format :

```
[u'10.07%', u'0.32%', u'-1.23%', u'-4.02%', u'-4.20%', u'-9.35%', u'-10.44%', u'-11.94%', u'-12.69%', u'-13.51%', u'-15.37%', u'-17.28%' ]
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The list consists of unicode strings.  If you want them to sort numerically, they need to bed sorted according to the float value of the strings.

Let's define your list:

```
>>> mylist = [u'-10.44%', u'-9.35%', u'-4.20%', u'-1.23%', u'-15.37%', u'-13.51%', u'-11.94%', u'10.07%', u'0.32%', u'-4.02%', u'-12.69%', u'-17.28%']
```

Now, let's sort it keyed to the float value of each string:

```
>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: float(x.rstrip('%')), reverse=True)
['10.07%', '0.32%', '-1.23%', '-4.02%', '-4.20%', '-9.35%', '-10.44%', '-11.94%', '-12.69%', '-13.51%', '-15.37%', '-17.28%']
```

Or, equivalently:

```
>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: -float(x.rstrip('%')))
['10.07%', '0.32%', '-1.23%', '-4.02%', '-4.20%', '-9.35%', '-10.44%', '-11.94%', '-12.69%', '-13.51%', '-15.37%', '-17.28%']
```